# Get postId in a wordpress pattern file?

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

How can I get post data or just post Id inside of a pattern?

I've created the following pattern file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Title: Post link
 * Slug: mytheme/post-link
 */
?>

<!-- wp:html -->

<div>
<?php 
    $id = $postId; //how can I get it????
    $post = get_post($postId);
    $slug = $post['slug'];
?>
<a href="<?= $slug; ?>">Some Button leading to a post</a>
</div>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

Comment: What is `$id` supposed to represent here? If it's the current post it doesn't really make sense for a button to be linking to itself. What's your goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In block themes patterns won't have access to context such as id it seems:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns

One has to create a custom block to get post id and use useSelect hook to get post Id like so:
`import { useSelect } from "@wordpress/data";`

...
inside Edit block function:

`const postId = useSelect(select => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId());`

then, postId can be used inside edit function and if it has to be used in save function, `useEffect` should be used inside edit to store id to attribute like so:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (postId) {
    setAttributes({postId})
  }, [postId]);
```

Provided you have defined postId attribute in `block.json`, you can get and use that attribute in save function or render_callback.

Comment: I edited your answer since it did not contain information how to properly get post Id in a block. Hopefully it will soon be approved.

Answer (score 0):

As I answered another question here: [How to access wp_query in block pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771714/how-to-access-wp-query-in-block-pattern) we can use a hack for this, and I don't know if there is any clean way to do that.

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$post_id = url_to_postid($url);
```

Comment: This is a good solution.